# Online Log-in and Registration Fatal Error

Tags: php

Please help me, this works perfectly on local but when I tried to make it online
It shows a **fatal error**, i tried making the **mysql_query** into **mysqli_query** still doesn't work, please help

[Here is my Online Register and Log-in](http://perezfidel.000webhostapp.com)

just view-source and please kindly help me what is wrong!!

Sorry if the language is In Bisaya! Just hover the mouse longer and the translation will show up, please help. This is just for a school project. Thanks in advance!

I just followed the instructions of Francis/howCode in youtube and changed some things...
[Making Social Networking from (Scratch) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz0diJIIM58&list=PLA7F9875BD031DC16)

Comment: _"i tried making the mysql_query into mysqli_query"_ - but you didn't. The fatal error says ` Call to undefined function mysql_query()`.

Comment: Yeah, i just changed it back to what it was before... Can you help me?

Comment: well, you need to change all calls to mysql_* functions to it's apropriate mysqli_*  version - and change also the parameters that need to be changed. We can't do that for you...

Comment: can you post your code sample?

Comment: The codes will scatter if i post it, i don't know why so i just uploaded the file
im new here, so please forgive me, this is only for my project and i wish to pass it on its due day.

https://openload.co/f/n57XujUhPG8/feedpost.zip

Comment: Please Help Me....